# What is the best way to setup the API application using Protractor?

Tags: continuous-integration, protractor

I'm setting up my front-end application to use continuous integration in CircleCI. Unit tests work fine, but end-to-end tests are not.

The problem is that it requires the backend (API) server to be running, and ours is in another completely different application. So, what is the best way to setup this backend server (thinking about CI)?

I thought about uploading it on heroku, but then I'd have to keep manually updating the code via git. Another option was to download the code to the CI VM and run the server directly there, but it is just too much work (install ruby, postgres, gems...), and it doesn't seem in no way the best option.

Have anyone passed through the same situation? How do you guys usually deal with this kind of situations?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing everything inside the CI. I made some custom scripts that configure the backend project every time the test suite is ran. Also, I cached the folder with the backend code and the gems (which was taking ~2min to install).

The configuring part now adds ~20 seconds to the total time, so it wasn't a big deal. Although I still think that this is probably not the best way to do this, it has some advantages, such as not worrying about updating the backend code (it pulls from master automatically) or its database (it runs `rake db:reset` after updating the code).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the API server is running *somewhere*, configure the front-end application to point there while in the test/CI environment, at least to start out. If there are multiple API environments, choose the one the most closely matches the front-end environment (e.g. dev, staging, etc).

It gets more complicated if/when you need to run the e2e tests each time the API is built or match up specific build versions of the front-end and the API. In that case you will have to run the API server as part of the test.

Comment: We have a production and a development environment, but neither one is a good match. The problem is that we need (should?) to reset the database before the tests, so we don't worry about state changes. Like you said, running the server along with the test is an option, and I'm almost convinced to do so, but it still seems like a workaround :(